# Google Chart Api: doesn't load data

Tags: javascript, rest, sdk, google-visualization, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using Google Charts API and i'm getting a issue which i cant understand. All code works well if i use the final alert("Im IN!"), but if i remove it my nArray is not filled. and i dont understand why.

This are global vars:

```
 var Chart;
 var data;
 var nArray;
```

This is where i fill my nArray so i can load into my chart.

```
function setArray(PlayerName,LeadPoints,OppPoints,PropPoints){

        var newPlayer = [PlayerName,LeadPoints,PropPoints,OppPoints,'Total'];

        nArray.push(newPlayer);

    }
```

This is where i go to CRM to bring data to and fill my array calling the  `setArray` function.

```
    function setPointsByEntity() {


    SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords(
        "gamify_ponto",
        "$select=gamify_Entidade,gamify_PlayerId,gamify_Pontos,gamify_gamify_utilizador_gamify_ponto/gamify_name&$orderby=gamify_PlayerId asc&$expand=gamify_gamify_utilizador_gamify_ponto",

        function (results) {


            if(results.length>0){

                for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
(...) // do something
    setArray(lastPlayer.Name,leadPoints,oppPoints,propPoints);



                }

            }
            else {
               alert("No Contact records are available to set as the primary contact for the account.");
                 }
        },

        errorHandler,

        function () {

        //OnComplete handler
        }
    );
```

This is where i load Visualization API, run google visualization, and define my drawVisualization function.

```
   // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
          google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

     // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);


    function drawVisualization() {



        // Create and populate the data table.
         data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(nArray);

      setLabelTotal(data);
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

      view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, {
         type: 'number',
         calc: function (dt, row) {
             // set offset to determine how far you want to move the labels
             var offset = MaxArray(nArray) *0.03; // 3% do valor total.
             return dt.getValue(row, 1) + dt.getValue(row, 2) + dt.getValue(row, 3) + offset;
         }
     },
     4]);


      var options = {title:"Pontos por Jogador",
                     width:500, height:300,
                     hAxis: {
                        textStyle: {'color': 'white'}},
                 isStacked: true,
                     legend: {
                    position: 'top'
                    },
                    series: {
             3: {
                 type: 'line',
                 color: 'grey',
                 lineWidth: 0,
                 pointSize: 0,
                 visibleInLegend: false
             }
         },

              vAxis: { 
                viewWindowMode:'explicit',
                viewWindow: {
                        max:MaxArray(nArray) + MaxArray(nArray)*0.3,
                        min:0
                    }
              },
                 animation:{
                            duration: 1000,
                            easing: 'linear'}
                    };

        // Create and draw the visualization.
         chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

         chart.draw(view, options);

      }
```

Finally when dom is ready i assign my nArray by invoking `setPointsByEntity()`. The problem here is if i comment the "alert("Im IN!");" Chart wont appear. It seems that the nArray is not define.

//  whenever the dom is ready

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

setPointsByEntity(); // This function fill my nArray
alert("Im IN!");
});
```

This question it may have to do with another one that i've posted before, please follow this  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040689/javascript-global-var-doesnt-work-using-sdk-rest-retrivemultiplerecords)

Comment: It seems that you have problem because of asynchronous call. You have to call `drawVisualization()` from end of `function (results) {...` when the array is created.

Comment: yes, but how that explains the fact that if i run the `alert("...");`  statement it works.

Comment: It works because while `alert()` is opened and you close it, some time passed and data are collected. It is similar as `setTimeout()` hint from your other question.

Comment: I understand that, but it seems that doesn't work. I tried to setTimeout(drawVisualization(), 3000); but it has not the same effect of alert.

Comment: Have you tried [**jQuery.when()**](https://api.jquery.co/jQuery.when/) ?  
Using this, you are able to wait until _Visualization API_ is loaded and then call `setPointsByEntity()` function...

Comment: Thanks for your sugestion but it doesn't work to me. i tried `$.when(getPlayers(),setPointsByEntity()).then(google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']}));`

Answer (score 1):

Move the `setPointsByEntity` from the document ready handler to a callback from the google loader, and then call the `drawVisualization` function at the end of the success handler of the AJAX call:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(setPointsByEntity);

function setPointsByEntity() {
    SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords(
        "gamify_ponto",
        "$select=gamify_Entidade,gamify_PlayerId,gamify_Pontos,gamify_gamify_utilizador_gamify_ponto/gamify_name&$orderby=gamify_PlayerId asc&$expand=gamify_gamify_utilizador_gamify_ponto",
        function (results) {
            if(results.length>0){
                for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
                    (...) // do something
                    setArray(lastPlayer.Name,leadPoints,oppPoints,propPoints);
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("No Contact records are available to set as the primary contact for the account.");
            }
            drawVisualization();
        },
        errorHandler,
        function () {
            //OnComplete handler
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Did this work? I might need to use Google Charts in Dynamics CRM soon.